# Unity not loading scripts properly when changing scenes

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

So I created a main menu for my school project (A unity Roguelike game) that is a different scene from the main game. So in the script for the main menu, I coded the button to change to my main game scene. This is where the problems occur, when I hit start game some of my game objects are in the wall and when I reach the exit to the next level I die. When I start the main menu scene and change the scene through my start button, the game starts off at Day 2 when it's supposed to start at Day 1.

Anyway here is where I think the problem lies

**Player.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


   public class Player : MovingObject
   {

       public Text healthText;
       public AudioClip movementSound1;
       public AudioClip movementSound2;
       public AudioClip chopSound1;
       public AudioClip chopSound2;
       public AudioClip fruitSound1;
       public AudioClip fruitSound2;
       public AudioClip sodaSound1;
       public AudioClip sodaSound2;


       private Animator animator;
       private int playerHealth;
       private int attackPower = 1;
       private int healthPerFruit = 5;
       private int healthPerSoda = 10;
       private int secondsUntilNextLevel = 1;`


private void OnDisable()
{
    GameController.Instance.playerCurrentHealth = playerHealth;
}

void Update()
{
    if (!GameController.Instance.isPlayerTurn)
    {
        return;
    }

    CheckIfGameOver();

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D objectPlayerCollidedWith)
{
    if (objectPlayerCollidedWith.tag == "Exit")
    {
        Invoke("LoadNewLevel", secondsUntilNextLevel);
        enabled = false;
    }
}

private void LoadNewLevel()
{
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

**UIControl.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class UIControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void LoadScene(string loadName)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(loadName);
    }

}
```

**GameController.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private BoardController boardController;
    private List<Enemy> enemies;
    private GameObject levelImage;
    private Text levelText;
    private bool settingUpGame;
    private int secondsUntilLevelStart = 2;
    private int currentLevel = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        Instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        boardController = GetComponent<BoardController>();
        enemies = new List<Enemy>();
    }

    void Start() 
    {
        InitializeGame();
    }

    private void InitializeGame()
    {
        settingUpGame = true;
        levelImage = GameObject.Find("Level Image");
        levelText = GameObject.Find("Level Text").GetComponent<Text>();
        levelText.text = "Day " + currentLevel;
        levelImage.SetActive(true);
        enemies.Clear();
        boardController.SetupLevel(currentLevel);
        Invoke("DisableLevelImage", secondsUntilLevelStart);
    }

    private void DisableLevelImage()
    {
        levelImage.SetActive(false);
        settingUpGame = false;
        isPlayerTurn = true;
        areEnemiesMoving = false;
    }

    private void OnLevelWasLoaded(int levelLoaded)
    {
        currentLevel++;
        InitializeGame();
    }




    public void GameOver()
    {
        isPlayerTurn = false;
        SoundController.Instance.music.Stop();
        SoundController.Instance.PlaySingle(gameOverSound);
        levelText.text = "You starved after " + currentLevel + " days...";
        levelImage.SetActive(true);
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

**BoardController.cs**

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class BoardController : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public int columns;
        public int rows;

        public GameObject[] floors;
        public GameObject[] outerWalls;
        public GameObject[] wallObstacles;
        public GameObject[] foodItems;
        public GameObject[] enemies;
        public GameObject exit;

        private Transform gameBoard;
        private List<Vector3> obstaclesGrid;

        void Awake()
        {
            obstaclesGrid = new List<Vector3>();

        }


        void Update()
        {

        }

        private void InitializeObstaclePositions()
        {
            obstaclesGrid.Clear();

            for(int x = 2; x < columns - 2; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 2; y < rows - 2; y++)
                {
                    obstaclesGrid.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetupGameBoard()
        {
            gameBoard = new GameObject("Game Board").transform;

            for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
                {

                    GameObject selectedTile;
                    if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == columns - 1 || y == rows - 1)
                    {
                        selectedTile = outerWalls[Random.Range(0, outerWalls.Length)];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        selectedTile = floors[Random.Range(0, floors.Length)];
                    }
                    GameObject floorTile = (GameObject)Instantiate(selectedTile, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
                    floorTile.transform.SetParent(gameBoard);
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetRandomObstaclesOnGrid(GameObject[] obstaclesArray, int minimum, int maximum)
        {
            int obstacleCount = Random.Range(minimum, maximum + 1);

            if(obstacleCount > obstaclesGrid.Count)
            {
                obstacleCount = obstaclesGrid.Count;
            }

            for(int index = 0; index < obstacleCount; index++)
            {

                GameObject selectedObstacle = obstaclesArray[Random.Range(0, obstaclesArray.Length)];
                Instantiate(selectedObstacle, SelectGridPosition(), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }

        private Vector3 SelectGridPosition()
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, obstaclesGrid.Count);
            Vector3 randomPosition = obstaclesGrid[randomIndex];
            obstaclesGrid.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
            return randomPosition;
        }

        public void SetupLevel(int currentLevel)
        {
            InitializeObstaclePositions();
            SetupGameBoard();
            SetRandomObstaclesOnGrid(wallObstacles, 3, 9);
            SetRandomObstaclesOnGrid(foodItems, 1, 5);
            int enemyCount = (int)Mathf.Log(currentLevel, 2);
            SetRandomObstaclesOnGrid(enemies, enemyCount, enemyCount);
            Instantiate(exit, new Vector3(columns - 2, rows - 2, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

These are the main scripts that have to do with this issue, my other scripts have to do with enemies and sound so I doubt I can find any issues there.

I apologize for the formatting, I'm  new at this.

Comment: For future notes, you almost never have to dump your entire solution onto the page... That basically just says, "I have literally no idea where the problem could be." And quite frankly I'm too lazy to read all of this. You didn't have to include anything to do with the sounds, for example.

Comment: I didn't really think about that I'll try to fix it, my understanding was that if someone were to help it would be more useful to see the entire thing.

Comment: Good to see you added your entire code base. The problem might be in the .csproj file though, please add that to your question. srs though, check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in what to include in your question.

Comment: I thought that too at first, but it normally comes down to a few lines of code that are important. But this might even by a Unity error, nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Having a quick look at it, when gamecontroller.cs starts, "InitializeGame" is called, which probably triggers 'OnLevelWasLoaded' when your board was set up - which then calls init.game again. Related to your objects being messy, loading two levels at the same time can be a very good reason or if I was wrong with double-initializing, you probably forget to destroy old objects before creating the new ones